# transposing dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, transpose

I have following file format:

```
SA BTSA01_U01 0 0 0 -9 G G T T    
SA BTSA01_U02 0 0 0 -9 G G T T
```

want to transpose it using pandas, following is the code I tried:

```
import pandas as pd from pandas import DataFrame 
  def transpose(file1,file2):
  source=pd.read_csv(file1,sep=None,engine='python')
  dest=source.transpose()
  dest.to_csv(file2)
```

But it did not give me the desire output,following is the output:

```
0    
SA  SA    
BTSA01_U01  BTSA01_U02    
0   0    
0.1 0   
0.2 0    
-9  -9    
G   G    
G.1 G    
T   T    
T.1 T
```

I tried using some of the options like, `header=False`, `index=False` with `dest.to_csv`, but none is working, I am wondering about addition of "." and "1" in some of the values in first column,

Comment: You've not specified the `header=None` so the names of the columns clash when you read the csv in. Also post your desired output, we can only guess at the moment

Comment: wow, thanks it worked!

Comment: Once loaded, you can also simpy use `source.T` to transpose the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify [`header=None`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) so your first line is being interpreted as column names but this will generate duplicate names which isn't allowed so you get `.1` appended.

So you need:

```
source=pd.read_csv(file1,sep=None,engine='python', header=None)
```